# Converting tickboxes in a form to any array in $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, post

What's the best way to collect data from a form using checkboxes so it's nicely grouped into one array from the $_POST array in the receiving page.

For example, in my form i'll have HTML which looks like this (x = ticked):

```
[x] Option One
[ ] Option Two
[x] Option Three
```

which i want to translated into an array from the $_POST array:

```
Array
(
    [a] => "Option One"
    [b] => "Option Three"
)
```

Is there a nice shortcut to doing this?

Comment: beginner and uninformed are synonyms, Gary.

Comment: additionally, uninformed is a person's characteristic, beginner is a question characteristic. we don't tag people on SO.

Comment: Here we go, start your engines, Edit Wars!!! *sigh* Is this really a beginner question? I thought a beginner question would be more along the lines of 'What's an array?'. And the kicker is i'm not a beginner using PHP, i've been using it for years. So this also isn't for beginners.

Comment: yes, it's a beginner question. and there are plenty dups on SO too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tickbox[a]" value="Option One" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="tickbox[b]" value="Option Two">
<input type="checkbox" name="tickbox[c]" value="Option Three" checked="checked">
```

yields

```
Array
(
   [a] => "Option One",
   [c] => "Option Three",
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add square-brackets to the end of the name:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="Option 1">
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="Option 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="Option 3">
```

This will come out as

```
Array
(
   [0] => "Option One",
   [1] => "Option Three",
)
```

if the middle one isn't ticked - hopefully close enough to what you want.

Comment: Thanks, i wondered if this approach would work and intended to try it later.